# Word Palindrome in JAVA (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

i want to know if there is something missing.
if i will input "race car" it must show  Palindrome and if i will input "string beans" it must show not a palindrome but when i run the code it has an error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
>           at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
>           at praktis.Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:11)

```
     public static void main (String args[]) {
        String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String:");
        String finalword = word.replaceAll(" ","").toLowerCase();

        for (int x = word.length(); x >= word.length()-1; x--) {
        //this is my line 11 // 
                 finalword.charAt(x);
       }
            if(word.equals(finalword)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome");
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a Palindrome");
            }
    }
```

Comment: `finalword.charAt(x)` doesn't do anything because you ignore the returned character. What do you intend for this to do?

Comment: As for the error, you should use a debugger to watch the values of `x` in your `for` loop. Alternatively, you can output the values of `x` and see what they are before the exception is thrown.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use the [Apache commons-lang library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`StringUtils.reverse()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverse%28java.lang.String%29) utility method.

Comment: i have already change my for (x = word.length(); x >= word.length()-1; x--) to for (x = word.length()-1; x >= 0; x--) and remove my line 11 there but when i try to run the code again it and everytime i input a string it always prints a PALINDROME even if it is not a palindrome.

Comment: You need to use a debugger or output statements to see what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for (x = word.length()-1; x >= 0; x--)`

EDIT:

```
String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String:");
        String finalword = "";
        int x;
        for (x = word.length()-1; x >= 0; x--) {
            finalword = finalword + word.charAt(x);
        }
        if (word.equals(finalword)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a Palindrome");
    }
```

Comment: i have already change my                                             for (x = word.length(); x >= word.length()-1; x--) to              for (x = word.length()-1; x >= 0; x--)   and remove my line 11 there but when i try to run the code again it and everytime i input a string it always prints a PALINDROME even if it is not a palindrome.

Comment: String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String:");
        String finalword = "";
        int x;
        for (x = word.length()-1; x >= 0; x--) {
            finalword = finalword + word.charAt(x);
        }
        if (word.equals(finalword)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a Palindrome");
        }

Comment: There is no need to loop over every character, you can reduce number of iterations by iterate only to the middle character, its just checking whether character in right side is equal to left side while coming to the middle. `public static boolean isPalindrome(String str){
  boolean result = false;
  for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= (str.length() - 1)/2; i--){
   if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i)){
    result = true;
   }else{
    result = false;
   }
  }
  return result;
 }`

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens because you are indexing at the length; you should be indexing from zero to length minus one:

```
for (x = word.length()-1; x >= 0 ; x--)
    ....
```

Additionally, calling `charAt(x)` does not change the string (in fact, no method you call on a string can change it: strings in Java are immutable). If you are composing a word in reverse, consider using `StringBuilder`, and append characters to it as you iterate the original word in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

You're utilizing `word.length()` to access a character in `finalword` when `finalword` will have a different length due to spaces being replaced. Also, a `String` is indexed from 0 to `length - 1` - exactly like an array, hence indexing it at `length()` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Since charAt() is 0-indexed, charAt(word.length()) will be one character AFTER the end of the string. Simply start x at word.length()-1. Hope that helps!